# Uploaded Files Are Not Viewable in Laravel. Permission Is Denied

Tags: iis, laravel

I am using laravel 4 on Windows Server 2012 with IIS.

I am able to upload a file to the server. When I go to view it, permission is denied.

I have another application that does not use laravel and I can upload files perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and searched over the net but couldn't get a solution. The problem is not Laravel specific, it's a general php issue on iis. This is a permission issue. When you upload a file using php the file first goes to the temp folder before your Laravel code moves it to the desired folder in you application. The issue here is that a different user account is used to write the file to temp folder thus when you move it to your application folder you can't view it. The simple solution is to modify the temp folder permission give your applicatio access to read and write. That's all. Hope this help someone else.

Comment: I have an application on my IIS server that can upload files perfectly. It is only the application that uses laravel that I am having issues with. The file is uploaded, I just cannot open it because of the permissions.

Comment: Is the other applications written in php.. Have you granted your application write and read access to temp folder at c://windows/temp.

Comment: Yes the other application is written in php. I have granted my application read/write access to the temp folder and it is still the same issue.

Comment: Please right click on the file uploaded and check the permission. Whatbisbthe the name of the user who have access to read and write on the file

Comment: The owner of the file is IUSR. The IUSR account has full control in permissions. I noticed the local account (DevTest) does not have any permissions. When I manually add the DevTest account to have permissions on that file, then I can view that file on the website. Any ideas?

Comment: Ya.. grant Devtest read and write permossion to the temp folder. That will solve the problem